# javascript validation for non empty,number and alphabets

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form that accepts name, phone no. Currently, I have done validation for non empty fields. I want to add validation for name (alphabets) and phone no.(numbers).

My current code is given below. On submitting the form, I will be calling `validateform()` function:

```
function validateform()
{
    var str= true;
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML="";

    if(document.frm.name.value=="")
    {
        document.getElementById("name").innerHTML="Please enter Name";
        str=false;
    }

    return str;
}
```

The value entered for name should be only alphabets. If not, I want to show the message "enter only alphabets". How should I do it?

Comment: tried anything? use regex (like `/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/` for only alphabets) to validate and throw the required error message.

Comment: Define “alphabets”. There are myriads of alphabetic characters. Which subset do you wish to allow? Should Müller, Poincaré, and Strauß be excluded?

Answer (score 2):

/*mobile number of 10 digits */

```
 var digit=10; 

 var pattern=/[0-9]{digit}/;

   if(!pattern.match ( phoneno ) )
         alert("not a valid number");
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, you can try something like this:

```
var rule = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/;
if(rule.test(document.frm.name.value)) {
   // this contains only letters !
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex to achive what you're trying to do.

```
    function validatePhonenumber(value) {
         var regexp = /^[0-9]+?$/;
         return regexp.test(value);
    }

    function validateAlphabet(value) {
         var regexp = /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/;
         return regexp.test(value);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var alphaExp = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
if(!document.frm.name.match(alphaExp))
    {
        document.getElementById("name").innerHTML="Please enter only alphabets";
        str=false;
    }

var numExp = /^[0-9]+$/;
if(!document.frm.phone.match(numExp))
    {
        document.getElementById("phone").innerHTML="Please enter only numbers";
        str=false;
    }
```

With this you don't need to check for empty input. If you want to handle empty input separately, replace `+` with a `*` in the regexes.

Answer (score 1):

```
function alphanumeric(inputtxt)  
{   
  var letters = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;  
  if(inputtxt.value.match(letters))  
  {  
    alert('Your registration number have accepted : you can try another');  
    document.form1.text1.focus();  
    return true;  
  }  
  else  
  {  
    alert('Please input alphanumeric characters only');  
    return false;  
  }  
}
```

See more [here](http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/letters-numbers-field.php#sthash.cfi5pJYD.dpuf).